# How do you assign a signal to a port of a multiplexer?

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to assign the value of the output of a multiplexer to a signal, but I can't find the way to do it.

This is the code of the library `work`.

```
entity mux4a1 is
    port(enable: in  std_logic;
         x:      in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         sel:    in  std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
         y:      out std_logic);
    end mux4a1;

architecture funcional of mux4a1 is
begin
    process(enable, x, sel)
    begin
        if enable = '0' then
            y <= '0';
        else
            case sel is
                when "00"   => y <= x(0);
                when "01"   => y <= x(1);
                when "10"   => y <= x(2);
                when others => y <= x(3);
            end case;
        end if;        
    end process;
end funcional;
```

This is my code:

```
entity practica1 is  
port (x: in    std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);        
      z: out    std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)); 
end practica1;

architecture apartadoE of practica1 is
  signal e: std_logic:= '1';
  signal i: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
  signal sel: std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
begin
  z(0) <= '0';
  z(2) <= '0';
  z(3) <= '0';
  i(0) <= x(3) and x(1);
  i(1) <= (not x(1)) and (not x(3));
  i(2) <= x(1);
  i(3) <= not x(1);
  -- here is the problem, i don´t how to assign it.
  z(1) <= mux: entity work.mux4a1 port map (e, i, sel);
end apartadoE;
```

Comment: Firstly, the instantiation of mux4a1 is not in the right place. That part should stand on its own. Then, in its `port map`, you currently only have (e, i, sel). So you haven't mapped the output, `y`. I think what you want is to change the `port map` to (e, i, sel, z(1)). Then z(1) will be assigned with the output of `mux`.

Comment: `z(1) <= mux` would match the syntax for a concurrent signal assignment statement where a colon found as a next lexical element causes a syntax error. Replace the line `z(1) <= mux: entity work.mux4a1 port map (e, i, sel);` with `mux: enitty work.mux4a1 port map (e, i, sel, z(1);` where the `y` association is the last of four. You can also use named association - `port map (enable => e, x => i, sel => sel, y => z(1))`

Comment: @user1155120 I have already managed to fix it, thank you very much!